# Message from Google: Limiting access to data in your Google Account

Tags: gmail, policy

I received the following message from Google (Gmail) regarding my email account:

---

> Hi,
>
> Although you don’t need to do anything, we wanted to let you know that the following apps may no longer be able to access some data in your Google Account, including your Gmail content. If these apps are unable to meet the deadline to comply with our updated data policy requirements, they'll lose access to your Account starting July 15th, 2019.
>
> Ubuntu
>
> We are making this change as part of ongoing efforts to make sure your data is protected and private.
>
> You can always view, manage and remove apps you’ve given access to your account by visiting your Google Account.
>
> Thanks,
> The Google Accounts team

---

What does this mean? I am using Evolution on Ubuntu 19.10 to access my Gmail.

Comment: I'm suspicious that it's called "Ubuntu".  It may not be Evolution.  Ubuntu has cloud capabilities.  Look under Settings->Online Accounts.  Do you have a Google account listed there?

Comment: Ubuntu 1**9**.10 is currently unsupported at Ask Ubuntu. Is that a typo?

Comment: Got similar message for "Email Meter" app.

Comment: I also got the same email for my mobile app

Comment: Sorry it is Ubuntu 19.04 not 19.10. Yes google accounts are listed in Online Accounts

Comment: So as Nmath suggested, I went to google account settings and security checkup. There were apps listed under "Third Party Access" which according to google have security issues. Both Gnome and Ubuntu were listed there. Presumably this is because google accounts are accessed by online accounts in settings. I had to remove both. Hopefully the issue is now resolved for me. But the point is what is it that online accounts don't comply with which causes google to complain?